# Vertical Marginal Cost curves

Tags: microeconomics, cost, marginal

When would a marginal cost curve be vertical? I understand this happens when the marginal cost jumps, from say 0 to 100, but in such a case, I think there should be a discontinuity rather than a vertical curve.